# onsenui the sliding menu not working when i move from page 1 to page 2 using myNavigator.pushPage() method

Tags: user-interface, slidingmenu, onsen-ui, navigator

i have a onsenui sliding menu. when i click one of the menu option (electronics), it takes me to page 1. from page 1 i use the navigator push method to navigate to page 2. In page 2 i do see the sliding menu, but nothing happens when i click or swipe the sliding menu. But when i navigate back to page 1, it works.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/onsenui.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/onsen-css-components.css">
    <script src="./js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">

    </head>
    <body>

    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
    <ons-page>
    <ons-sliding-menu main-page="main.html" menu-page="menu.html" var="menu" swipeable=true max-slide-distance="200px">
    </ons-sliding-menu>
    </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>  

    <ons-template id="main.html">
    <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Navigator - Main Page</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div style="text-align: center">
    <br>
    <ons-button modifier="light"
      ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('page1.html', {hoge: 'hoge'})">
      Push Page 1
    </ons-button>
    </div>
    </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page>
    <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('main.html', {closeMenu: true})">Clothes</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">Electronics</ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
    <div class="center">Page 1</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div style="text-align: center">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <ons-button modifier="light"
      ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('page2.html', {title: 'Page'})">
      Push Page
      </ons-button>

    <ons-button modifier="light"
      ng-click="myNavigator.popPage()">
      Pop Page
    </ons-button>
    </div>
    </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
    <div class="center">Page 2</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div style="text-align: center">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <ons-button modifier="light"
      ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('page2.html', {title: 'Page'})">
      Push Page
      </ons-button>

    <ons-button modifier="light"
      ng-click="myNavigator.popPage()">
      Pop Page
    </ons-button>
    </div>
    </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent element in your code is an `ons-navigator` and you have a `sliding-menu` as its direct child. You can see the navigator as a frame that change its content every time you push or pop a page. Therefore, with its default content, the sliding menu, you are able to use it normally. Actually this sliding menu is another frame that contains your `main.html`. The problem is that, when you push to "page 2", you are using the navigator's method to change **all its content**, including that sliding menu.

You can invert the order of your navigator and sliding menu, so when you change the content of the navigator, the sliding menu will remain as the outer frame.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. i placed the sliding menu in the outer frame